# How to disable stackdriver logging in a spring application for a GCP project without creating a new docker image

Tags: spring, logback, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, spring-cloud-gcp

I have a spring application packaged inside a docker image and running in GKE pods. I want to disable stackdriver logging but only for this application in gke. Is there any env variable/property I can change in my spring application to disable this? I am using these two jars -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I found one method i.e. to change application.properties to

```
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=false
stackdriver.log.level=OFF
```

But for this I will have to create a new docker image and redeploy. Is there any way I can do directly in my kubernetes yaml/env variable?

**Update** - these two variables in application.properties only worked once(stopped logging to stackdriver) and now its again logging to stackdriver. Strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to rebuild your container image. Spring applications can pull application properties from environment variables. Probably for some very good reason, the names require remapping. So

**spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled** becomes **SPRING_CLOUD_GCP_LOGGING_ENABLED**.

Your k8s pod definition allows passing in environment variables as part of a container specification (just like docker compose):

```
 spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: myimage:latest
        env:
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_GCP_LOGGING_ENABLED
          value: false
```

Apply the changes to the pod with the following. Your pod will be restarted.

```
kubectl apply -f <pod-definition-file.yaml>
```

stackdriver.log.level  is left for you.  I can't promise you that any of this will turn off logging, only that this will update application properties without requiring you to rebuild the container.

Comment: So I dont need to set log level OFF in environment variables ?

Comment: I don't know about that.  I was only showing you snippet.